# field rules: serverdefault vs. readonly

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I want to use a custom datetime attribute to track, when an item entered a given state for the first time (serverdefault:clock).
To avoid later manipulation, this custom field at the same time should be set to readonly for everyone.

It seems however that in all combinations I come up with the "readonly" takes precedence and immediat es ly blocks the "serverdefault" that seems to be executed with the rights of the user iniziating tha transition.

For e.g. "created date" however the behavior seems possible for the system itself ...

Is there a way to achieve the same behavior for custom fields?

Answer (score 0):

You can define your field like this:

```
 <FIELD name="Custom Date" refname="My.CustomDate" type="DateTime">
    <WHENNOTCHANGED field="System.State">
      <READONLY />
    </WHENNOTCHANGED>
  </FIELD>
```

and then add this XML to the TRANSITION node for the given state:

```
<TRANSITION from="Resolved" to="Closed">
   <FIELDS>
      <FIELD refname="My.CustomDate">
        <SERVERDEFAULT from="clock" />
      </FIELD>
   </FIELDS>
</TRANSITION>
```